# Symfony3 create form without entity in type file

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have created a form in my controller like this :

```
$data = array ();
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder ( $data );
$formBuilder->add( 'Field1', NumberType::class, array(
                    'constraints' => array(
                            new NotBlank(),
                    ),
            ) )
            ->add ( 'Field2', NumberType::class, array(
                    'constraints' => array(
                            new NotBlank(),
                    )
...);
$form = $formBuilder->getForm ();
```

I am trying to put my form creation in a Type file. I did this like this but the form is not created and I can't display form fields in my view.I don't understand why.

```
#in ControlController
$data = array ();
$formBuilder= $this->createFormBuilder(ControlType::class, $data);
$form = $formBuilder->getForm ();

#in ControlType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder->add( 'Field1', NumberType::class, array(
                    'constraints' => array(
                            new NotBlank(),
                    ),
            ) )
            ->add ( 'Field2', NumberType::class, array(
                    'constraints' => array(
                            new NotBlank(),
                    )....;
}
```

Edit 1 :
I have tried all things you tell me, but it still doesn't work.
My code looks like this now :

```
#in ControlController
$data = ['Field1' => null, 'Field2' => null];
$formBuilder= $this->createFormBuilder(ControlType::class, $data);
$form = $formBuilder->getForm ();
return $this->render ( 'MeTestBundle:Control:index.html.twig', array (
            'form' => $form->createView () 
    ) );

#in ControlType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder->add( 'Field1', NumberType::class, array(
                            'mapped' => false,
    ) )
    ->add ( 'Field2', NumberType::class, array(
            'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(),
            ),
            'mapped' => false
    ))
    ->add ( 'save', SubmitType::class, array (
            'label' => 'Control'
    ));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Control::class,
    ));
}
```

But now the error I have is:

```
The options "Field1", "Field2" do not exist. Defined options are: "action", 
"allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", 
"compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", 
"csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", 
"empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", 
"inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", 
"label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", 
"property_path", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", 
"upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups".
```

Comment: $data = ['Field1' => null, 'Field2' => null];  And make sure you are in dev mode so you see the error messages.  And of course ensure $form is being passed to your twig template and the template is working as wanted.

Comment: The error message I have is : Neither the property "Field1" nor one of the methods "Field1()", "getField1()"/"isField1()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView"

Comment: Hence the $data = ... suggestion.

Comment: try this http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#building-the-form
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html

check this method too -- 'form' => $form->createView(),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Controller Code to create the Form seems to be wrong.

The Signature for createFormBuilder in Controller is defined like:

```
public function createFormBuilder($data = null, array $options = array())
```

What you want should be:

```
$data = ['Field1' => null, 'Field2' => null];
$form = $this->createForm(ControlType::class, $data);
return $this->render ( 'MeTestBundle:Control:index.html.twig', array (
        'form' => $form->createView () 
));
```

Edit: 
Also you should not set a `data_class` if you're not gonna use a data object.
Just leave `configureOptions` empty in this case.
If you want to use an Entity you should pass an instance of it as `$data` instead of a simple array.